# R and rgl: strange behaviour in range when using points3d

Tags: r, rgl

I've been struggling to find out a proper way to show 3d points using rgl. I've tried using `points3d` and `spheres3d` but with no success til now. Look what I did:

```
require(rgl)
x = runif(10, 0, 1)
y = runif(10, 0, 1)
z = runif(10, 0, 100)
test<-data.frame(x=x, y=y, z=z)

points3d(test$x,test$y,test$z,col='red',size=3)
box3d()
```

[image: points3d with problem in scale]

I read this https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?func=detail&group_id=234&aid=4933&atid=946 but with no success as well.

If I multiply the `x` and `y` by 100 I can get what I want:

```
test<-data.frame(x=x*100, y=y*100, z=z)
```

[image: points3d with a workaground]

However, considering the values from `x,y,z` can assume different precision values, I would need to create something *to put every variable in the same scale*(?).

Is there a better way to avoid problems with scaling when using `points3d`? I must use `points3d` or perhaps `sphere3d` (instead of using the `plot3d` directly) because I need to overlay the points with a surface.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `aspect3d` function you can use to specify the relative scalings.

```
points3d(test$x,test$y,test$z,col='red',size=3)
box3d()

aspect3d(c(1,1,1))
axes3d()
```

[image]